# Hashfunction to map combinations of 5 to 7 cards

Tags: hash-function

Referring to the original problem: [Optimizing hand-evaluation algorithm for Poker-Monte-Carlo-Simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412698/optimizing-hand-evaluation-algorithm-for-poker-monte-carlo-simulation)

I have a list of 5 to 7 cards and want to store their value in a hashtable, which should be an array of 32-bit-integers and directly accessed by the hashfunctions value as index.
Regarding the large amount of possible combinations in a 52-card-deck, I don't want to waste too much memory.

Numbers:

- 7-card-combinations: 133784560
- 6-card-combinations:  20358520
- 5-card-combinations:   2598960
- Total: 156.742.040 possible combinations

Storing 157 million 32-bit-integer values costs about 580MB. So I would like to avoid increasing this number by reserving memory in an array for values that aren't needed.

So the question is: How could a hashfunction look like, that maps each possible, non duplicated combination of cards to a consecutive value between 0 and 156.742.040 or at least comes close to it?

Comment: Eh, maybe a bitmap to represent the cards?

Comment: Each card has an ID by which it is represented: Two of Diamonds = 0, Ace of Clubs = 51. Now I want to have a unique value for all non-duplicate possible combinations of 5 to 7 cards for mapping it to an array.

Comment: Well: two of diamonds = `1<<0` and ace of clubs is `1<<51` and add them up. Voila: a bitmask. (you might invent a more compact code if there are fewer than 52 cards)

Comment: Valid, but this comes up with a maximum value of 2^51 which is obviously much more than needed.

Comment: Well, but... Maybe use this bitmask somehow...

Comment: ... or use fewer cards. Or use (Zobrist-) hashing.

Comment: Using fewer cards is no option. But maybe using a multidimensional array to map to like in zobrist-hashing (if I understood that correctly) is a good idea.

Comment: Computer-chess has been around for more than fifty years. It is very hard _not_ to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'm not sure adding your combinations is valid, in this case. In order to distinguish between a 5 cad and 7 card hand, they would have to be fundamentally different. 52 (deck complexity) fits into 2^6 (64), so you have 6 bits per card, making a 5 card hand a 30 bit number and a 7 card hand a 42 bit number. In other words, a 5 card hand fits within the storage space of a 7 card hand, and you can easily distinguish between them by their length.

Comment: The only possible collision would be a 6-card hand that starts with the card numbered `000000` and a 5-card hand that is the same without the card numbered `000000`; but you could solve this by either sorting each hand (largest first) or making your cards start at `000001` (which makes the hands distinct, as `000000` becomes a code for no-card). This admittedly only trims 23 million entries from your index, but still... worth considering.

Comment: My previous two comments are admittedly pretty far off topic. But I'm curious, what do you mean when you say you want the hash table to store the **value** of the hand? Which cards are in it? Or, like in your original question, the [**rank**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands) of the hand? (Where higher numbered hands beat lower numbered hands, or vice versa.)

Comment: @PatrickM: You are basicly right. The problem is hard to explain. I don't want to have different values for same card-combinations in different order PLUS I want all values to be consecutive, meaning without gaps which I would have if I just leave out a combination I had before in other order. Hope this explaination is proper...

Comment: Hmm consecutive order makes this a problem. A [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) does not grant consecutive order. The proper mathematical term for what you want is a [map function](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/content/function/definitions.html). I have an idea for what you want, let me see if I can find some time to flesh it out today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul Senzee has a great post on this for 7 cards (deleted link as it is broken and now points to a NSFW site).

His code is basically a bunch of pre-computed tables and then one function to look up the array index for a given 7-card hand (represented as a 64-bit number with the lowest 52 bits signifying cards):

```
inline unsigned index52c7(unsigned __int64 x)
{
    const unsigned short *a = (const unsigned short *)&x;
    unsigned A    = a[3],                B    = a[2],                        C    = a[1],            D   = a[0],
             bcA  = _bitcount[A],        bcB  = _bitcount[B],                bcC  = _bitcount[C],    bcD = _bitcount[D],
             mulA = _choose48x[7 - bcA], mulB = _choose32x[7 - (bcA + bcB)], mulC = _choose16x[bcD];
    return _offsets52c[bcA]                      + _table4[A] * mulA + 
           _offsets48c[ (bcA << 4)        + bcB] + _table [B] * mulB +
           _offsets32c[((bcA + bcB) << 4) + bcC] + _table [C] * mulC + 
                                                   _table [D];
}
```

In short, it's a bunch of lookups and bitwise operations powered by pre-computed lookup tables based on perfect hashing.

If you go back and look at [this website](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html), you can get the perfect hash code that Senzee used to create the 7-card hash and repeat the process for 5- and 6-card tables (essentially creating a new `index52c7.h` for each). You might be able to smash all 3 into one table, but I haven't tried that.

All told that should be ~628 MB (4 bytes * 157 M entries). Or, if you want to split it up, you can map it to 16-bit numbers (since I believe most poker hand evaluators only need 7,462 unique hand scores) and then have a separate map from those 7,462 hand scores to whatever hand categories you want. That would be 314 MB.

Comment: Yep, that's what I needed. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different answer based on the colex function concept. It works with bitsets that are sorted in descending order. Here's a Python implementation (both recursive so you can see the logic and iterative). The main concept is that, given a bitset, you can always calculate how many bitsets there are with the same number of set bits but less than (in either the lexicographical or mathematical sense) your given bitset. I got the idea from [this paper on hand isomorphisms](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./waugh/publications/isomorphism13.pdf).

```
from math import factorial


def n_choose_k(n, k):
    return 0 if n < k else factorial(n) // (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k))


def indexset_recursive(bitset, lowest_bit=0):
    """Return number of bitsets with same number of set bits but less than
    given bitset.

    Args:
      bitset (sequence) - Sequence of set bits in descending order.
      lowest_bit (int) - Name of the lowest bit. Default = 0.

    >>> indexset_recursive([51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45])
    133784559
    >>> indexset_recursive([52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46], lowest_bit=1)
    133784559
    >>> indexset_recursive([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
    0
    >>> indexset_recursive([7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], lowest_bit=1)
    0

    """
    m = len(bitset)
    first = bitset[0] - lowest_bit
    if m == 1:
        return first
    else:
        t = n_choose_k(first, m)
        return t + indexset_recursive(bitset[1:], lowest_bit)


def indexset(bitset, lowest_bit=0):
    """Return number of bitsets with same number of set bits but less than
    given bitset.

    Args:
      bitset (sequence) - Sequence of set bits in descending order.
      lowest_bit (int) - Name of the lowest bit. Default = 0.

   >>> indexset([51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45])
    133784559
    >>> indexset([52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46], lowest_bit=1)
    133784559
    >>> indexset([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
    0
    >>> indexset([7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], lowest_bit=1)
    0

    """
    m = len(bitset)
    g = enumerate(bitset)
    return sum(n_choose_k(bit - lowest_bit, m - i) for i, bit in g)
```

Comment: This seems to be slower than evaluating the poker hand on the fly.