# Efficient way to randomly select set bit

Tags: c#, algorithm, random, montecarlo, bitmask

My current hobby project provides Monte-Carlo-Simulations for card games with *French* decks (52 cards, from 2 to Ace).

To simulate as fast as possible, I use to represent multiple cards as bitmasks in some spots. Here is some (simplified) code:

```
public struct Card
{
    public enum CardColor : byte { Diamonds = 0, Hearts = 1, Spades = 2, Clubs = 3 }
    public enum CardValue : byte { Two = 0, Three = 1, Four = 2, Five = 3, Six = 4, Seven = 5, Eight = 6, Nine = 7, Ten = 8, Jack = 9, Queen = 10, King = 11, Ace = 12 }

    public CardColor Color { get; private set; }
    public CardValue Value { get; private set; }

    // ID provides a unique value for each card, ranging from 0 to 51, from 2Diamonds to AceClubs
    public byte ID { get { return (byte)(((byte)this.Value * 4) + (byte)this.Color); } }

    // --- Constructors ---
    public Card(CardColor color, CardValue value)
    {
        this.Color = color;
        this.Value = value;
    }
    public Card(byte id)
    {
        this.Color = (CardColor)(id % 4);
        this.Value = (CardValue)((id - (byte)this.Color) / 4);
    }
}
```

The structure which holds multiple cards as bitmask:

```
 public struct CardPool
 {
    private const ulong FULL_POOL = 4503599627370495;

    internal ulong Pool { get; private set; } // Holds all cards as set bit at Card.ID position

    public int Count()
    {
        ulong i = this.Pool;
        i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555);
        i = (i & 0x3333333333333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333);
        return (int)((((i + (i >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0F) * 0x101010101010101) >> 56);
    }

    public CardPool Clone()
    {
        return new CardPool() { Pool = this.Pool };
    }

    public void Add(Card card)
    {
        Add(card.ID);
    }
    public void Add(byte cardID)
    {
        this.Pool = this.Pool | ((ulong)1 << cardID);
    }

    public void Remove(Card card)
    {
        Remove(card.ID);
    }
    public void Remove(byte cardID)
    {
        this.Pool = this.Pool & ~((ulong)1 << cardID);
    }

    public bool Contains(Card card)
    {
        ulong mask = ((ulong)1 << card.ID);
        return (this.Pool & mask) == mask;
    }

    // --- Constructor ---
    public CardPool(bool filled)
    {
        if (filled)
            this.Pool = FULL_POOL;
        else
            this.Pool = 0;
    }

}
```

I want to draw one or more cards at random from the second struct *CardPool*, but I cannot imagine how to do that without iterating single bits in the pool.
Is there any known algorithm to perfom this? If not, do you have any idea of doing this fast?

**Update**:
The structure is not intended to draw all cards from. It gets cloned frequently and cloning an array is no option. I really think of bitoperations for drawing one or multiple cards.

**Update2**:
I wrote a class which holds the cards as List for comparison.

```
public class CardPoolClass
{
    private List<Card> Cards;
    public void Add(Card card)
    {
        this.Cards.Add(card);
    }

    public CardPoolClass Clone()
    {
        return new CardPoolClass(this.Cards);
    }

    public CardPoolClass()
    {
        this.Cards = new List<Card> { };
    }
    public CardPoolClass(List<Card> cards)
    {
        this.Cards = cards.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comparing 1.000.000 clone operations of full decks:
- struct: 17 ms
- class: 73 ms

Admitted: The difference is not as much as I thought.
But taken into account that I additionally give up the easy lookup of precalculated values, this makes a big difference.
Of course, it would be faster to draw a random card with this class, but I would have to calculate an index for lookup then, what just transfers the problem to another spot.

**I repeat my initial question**: Is there a known algorithm for choosing a random set bit from an integer value or has someone an idea for getting this done faster than to iterate all bits?

The discussion about using a class with a List or an Array takes us nowhere, this is not my question and I am able to elaborate on my own if I would be better off using a class.

**Update3**, the lookup-code:

CODE DELETED: This might be misleading because it does not refer to passages which performance suffers from what is subject of the thread.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to get (and remove) a random set bit from a 52-bit number. Do you want to do that successively a number of times, or does the number change another way between two draws ? Also, why not just make an array of (maximum) 52 cards ? That would be more practical to use.

Comment: The array would be more practical, thats correct, but with less performance, and, additionally, I use the ulong as index for a dictionary to look up precalculated values.

Comment: Not necessarily removing in the same procedure, but yes, I want to get a random bit from a 52-bit number. Ideally working successively.

Comment: Is performance a **real** and **justified** concern in your case? Or are you just learning bit operations?

Comment: Performance is the most important aspect. I do wrapping with more practical classes to the outside of the library. The simulations rely on huge numbers.

Comment: I don't see how an array would lead to a loss of performance, except, indeed, for a dictionary look-up. But even then, it depends on how frequently you do these look-ups. You say that you don't necessarily want to remove the card from the pool when you draw it ; does that mean a card can be drawn twice in a row ?

Comment: No, it cannot be drawn twice in a row. But it would be sufficient to draw one, then remove it, draw another and so on. The HUGE performance loss comes with cloning this struct, which has to be down frequently during simulation.

Comment: Do you ever actually need to add a card back to the deck? Fact is, a bit-field is _unordered_. You simply cannot have a shuffled deck using only a bit-field. The classic approach to card decks is an array of card IDs (or better, card objects that implement suit and value separately). What is the "cloning" scenario? Assuming each clone should have the same card order, that can be done by copying a reference (backing array) and an `int` (the current draw position in the array). Barring that, you're not going to get out of an array copy and shuffle.

Comment: Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly the exact scenario you're dealing with, explain what that code does and (since you claim performance is the highest priority) explain what you've done to measure performance, what performance you've observed, what performance you expect to get instead, and why you think that performance goal is reasonable and achievable. As stated your question is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The complete scenario would cleary go beyond the scope of this thread. Performance has the highest priority because I gave it the highest priority, this is not a "claim". No one wants to wait half an hour for a simulation. My question is clear, precise and not too broad, with all needed code included. But I will add the currend method with running times if this helps.

Comment: @Peter: The first structure is a Card which holds color and value seperatly.

Comment: @Peter: The difference between instanciating a class and a struct is by itsself factor 10. Not to mention the difference between copying an integer compared to cloning an array when it comes to cloning.

Comment: Can you show the look-up code ? I can't imagine you have a table of 2^52 entries. That might help narrow the problem.

Comment: Okay... I add the code.

Comment: @Nelxiost: There are about 160.000.000 precalculated values

Comment: So, you only ever have 5, 6 or 7 cards in your pool (that would be 156742040 values) ? You compared copying times for full decks. That's misleading. If you aren't ever copying full decks, then don't profile with full decks.

Comment: Yes, all 5, 6 and 7 Card combinations. I am cloning almost full decks most of the time. The precalculations don't need cloning. As you can see in the code, it's no cloning involved. During simulation, there is much cloning.

Comment: Oh, my bad then. I thought this was where you were copying the most (you copy `pool` at least once each time you add it to `Values`).

Comment: As a side note, you don't really need `Card` and related overhead for simulation - a card can be represented as a single integer - its number in a sorted deck. Checking the suit or rank is as easy as `div`/`mod`. `Card` can still be used as a set of convenience methods. The same goes for a deck - a single 64-bit integer as a bitmask is just fine.

Comment: @ivan: Under the hood, it is exactly like that. But this would't be nice to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a same card cannot be drawn twice in a row, you can place every card (in your case, the indices of `Pool`'s set bits) in an array, shuffle it, and pop the cards one by one from any end of this array.

Here's a pseudo-code (because I don't know C#).

```
declare cards as an array of indices

for each bit in Pool
    push its index into cards

shuffle cards

when a card needs to be drawn
    pop an index from cards
    look up the card with Card(byte id)
```

**Edit**

Here's an algorithm to get a random set bit once in a 64-bit integer, using a code from [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) to get position of a bit with given rank (number of more significant set bits).

```
ulong v = this.Pool;
// ulong a = (v & ~0UL/3) + ((v >> 1) & ~0UL/3);
ulong a = v - ((v >> 1) & ~0UL/3);
// ulong b = (a & ~0UL/5) + ((a >> 2) & ~0UL/5);
ulong b = (a & ~0UL/5) + ((a >> 2) & ~0UL/5);
// ulong c = (b & ~0UL/0x11) + ((b >> 4) & ~0UL/0x11);
ulong c = (b + (b >> 4)) & ~0UL/0x11;
// ulong d = (c & ~0UL/0x101) + ((c >> 8) & ~0UL/0x101);
ulong d = (c + (c >> 8)) & ~0UL/0x101;
ulong t = (d >> 32) + (d >> 48);

int bitCount = ((c * (~0UL / 0xff)) >> 56);
ulong r = Randomizer.Next(1, bitCount+1);

ulong s = 64;
// if (r > t) {s -= 32; r -= t;}
s -= ((t - r) & 256) >> 3; r -= (t & ((t - r) >> 8));
t = (d >> (s - 16)) & 0xff;
// if (r > t) {s -= 16; r -= t;}
s -= ((t - r) & 256) >> 4; r -= (t & ((t - r) >> 8));
t = (c >> (s - 8)) & 0xf;
// if (r > t) {s -= 8; r -= t;}
s -= ((t - r) & 256) >> 5; r -= (t & ((t - r) >> 8));
t = (b >> (s - 4)) & 0x7;
// if (r > t) {s -= 4; r -= t;}
s -= ((t - r) & 256) >> 6; r -= (t & ((t - r) >> 8));
t = (a >> (s - 2)) & 0x3;
// if (r > t) {s -= 2; r -= t;}
s -= ((t - r) & 256) >> 7; r -= (t & ((t - r) >> 8));
t = (v >> (s - 1)) & 0x1;
// if (r > t) s--;
s -= ((t - r) & 256) >> 8;
s--; // s is now the position of a random set bit in v
```

The commented lines make another version, with branches. If you want to compare the two versions, uncomment these lines and comment the lines following them.

In the original code, the last line is `s = 65 - s`, but since you use `1 << cardID` for manipulations on card pools, and `r` is random anyway, `s--` gives the correct value.

The only thing to watch out for is a zero value for `v`. But executing this code on an empty pool would be meaningless anyway.

Comment: This would be an acceptable solution. But it is not intended to draw all cards from the pool till its cloned. I expect to draw 1 to max 10 cards. So the whole procedure will be lost when cloning.

Comment: Well, it might still be faster than iterating over every set bit each time. Again, it depends on how frequently you do each operation. All you can do at this point is profiling. Otherwise, with your current design, you are basically stuck with those two solutions as well as Yves'.

Comment: After some more research, it turns out there is a quick way to get one random set bit (probably faster than iterating over every bit).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: That's amazingly 9 times faster than iterating all bits and surprisingly only 2.5 times slower than drawing from a ready-to-use array. Sadly, I didn't get it to work correctly yet, the final number sometimes exceeds the max value.

Comment: [Let's take that into a chatroom if you wish.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122690/room-for-martin-tausch-and-nelxiost)