# Determining Poker Hand Strength via Bit Manipulation

Tags: bit-shift, bitmask, poker, nibble

I'm following this: [Optimizing hand-evaluation algorithm for Poker-Monte-Carlo-Simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412698/optimizing-hand-evaluation-algorithm-for-poker-monte-carlo-simulation)

My setup is similar -- an unsigned long to represent the board and the player's holding. All cards are bit flags, starting at 1 and ending at 2^51.

For example, 2c is 1, 3c is 16, 4c is 256, and As is 2^51. So, the hand

1010 0000 1001 0000 0000 0100 0000 0001 0000 0000 0010 is

Qs Qd 7h 5c 2d (the board) + Ts Tc (the player's holding).

The link I referred to explains well how to find a straight flush / four of a kind, and it works. However, I seem to have hit a brick wall trying to identify three of a kind. I've tried:

- hand & (hand >> 1) & (hand >> 2) & 0x1111111111111111 -- the naive case, following the example from the link;
- hand & (hand >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333 -- this seems to catch all three of a kind, but it misclassifies pairs (e.g. the example above) as trips;
- and variations thereof.

**How do I dismiss all nibbles with fewer than three set bits?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is closely related to calculating the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight). That is you are insterested in the number of set bits for each nibble. The steps to start with are:

```
int64 w = hand - ((hand >> 1) & 0x55555555);
w = (w & 0x33333333) + ((w >> 2) & 0x33333333);
```

This results in the number of set bits of each nibble in w. You'd then check each nibble of w to contain 3. Like so: `if ((w & 0xf) == 0x3 || (w & 0xf0) == 0x30 ...`.